# Convergence in distribution: constant multiplication

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

If I have $$X_n/\sigma$$ converging in distribution to $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, does this mean I can just multiply through with $\sigma$ and obtain that  $X_n$ converges to a standard normal?

I have a book which gives the definition of convergence in distribution, and then uses this intuitive result, yet it does not give a proof of it. Is it immediately obvious? How?

EDIT: I am not interested in this being a special case of some complicated theorem. What my problem is that the book does not prove it, so I want to know why it is obvious.

Comment: It is obvious because a complicated theorem demonstrates it.

Comment: Is this a serious contribution, or are you trying to be funny?

Comment: @Geneo Do you mean that $X_n\to\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$? If this is the case, then $X_n/\sigma\to\mathcal N(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of the convergence in distribution, we have that
$$
P(X_n/\sigma\le x)\to P(Y\le x)
$$
as $n\to\infty$, where $Y\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$. Also,
$$
P(X_n\le \sigma x)\to P(\sigma Y\le \sigma x)
$$
as $n\to\infty$. Hence, $X_n\to\sigma Y$ in distribution as $n\to\infty$ and $\sigma Y\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^4)$.